# returning length of a string

Tags: c, function

I saw someone post this function which returns the length of a string. Can someone explain to me line by line what happens because I don't get what's going on with the *s pointer and how it is able to walk through the string one by one and calculate the amount of characters in the string. This function is from FreeBSD

```
size_t
strlen(const char *str)
{
const char *s;
for (s = str; *s; ++s);
return(s - str);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a "explain code to me line by line" site.

Comment: How much do you already know about pointers, pointer arithmetic, and logical conditions in C?

Comment: I know mostly what's going on. Just confused what  *s;  is doing. Geeze. I didn't think it was such a big deal for a small amount of code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @re.m7 see my comment under the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
size_t
strlen(const char *str)
{
const char *s; // init pointer
for (s = str; *s; ++s); // set pointer to beginning of str, and increment pointer until
                        // you reach '\0', which is the end of the string
return(s - str); // compute the distance between end and beginning of string
                 // (s points to end of string, str points to beginning of string)
}
```

Comment: And `*s` as the second expression in the `for` loop, is an implicit evaluation, testing if `*s` points to `'\0`', the string terminator. Until `'\0'` is met, any non-0 value is true, that is, the loop continues.

Comment: Thank you. For the explanation. I never really looked into implicit evaluation

Comment: @re.m7 in C, some people like to use definitions `true` and `false` explicitly. But the language works that any expression that evaluates to `0` is logically false, anything else is true when used implicitly, for example `if (apples)` need not specify how many you have (or owe ;) to be true.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Now I understand what's happening. So eventually it will keep looping till it hits null hence null terminator. Then that's when it exits and gets returned